# Мне нужно сделать чтобы один список добавить в другой, но при этом была правильная сортировка

Tags: python, список, link

Я добавляю один список в другой, но при выводе я получаю не то что нужно, элементы списка svarka2 не чередуются так же как элементы списка svarka

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'



def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_='mhide')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text())
    else:
        return 1

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    i = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-navbar')
    for item in i:
        proba = item.find('ul', class_='menu').get_text(strip=True)
    for item2 in items:
        stranica = item2.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href')
    svarka = []
    for item in items:
        svarka.append({
            "title": item.find('div', class_='b-products__title').get_text(strip=True),
            "text": item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get_text(strip=True),
            "label": item.find('ul', class_='b-products__labels').get_text(strip=True).replace(':', ': '),
            "price": item.find('span', class_='b-products__price').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', '').replace('р', '.00').replace('\xa0', ''),
            "image": item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src'),
            "articul": item.find('div', class_='b-products__meta').get_text(strip=True).replace('Артикул: ',''),
            "proba": proba,
        })
    svarka2 = []
    for item in items:
        svarka2.append({
            "stranica": item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href'),
            })
    svarka.extend(svarka2)
    return svarka

def perehod(svarka):
    svarka2 = svarka["title"]
    return svarka2


def save_file(svarka, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Описание', 'Лейбел', 'Цена', 'Картинка', 'Артикул', 'Ссылка', 'Проба', 'Большое описание'])
        global item
        for item in svarka:
            writer.writerow((item.get("title"), item.get("text"), item.get("label"), item.get("price"), item.get("image"), item.get("articul"), item.get("stranica"), item.get("proba"), 'rub'))

def djfdk ():
    save_file(svarka, FILE)
    print(f'Получено {len(svarka)} сварочных аппаратов')
    os.startfile(FILE)


def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        svarka = get_content(html.text)
        save_file(svarka, FILE)
        print(f'Получено {len(svarka)} сварочных аппаратов')
        os.startfile(FILE)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

[image]
Мне нужно чтобы ссылки которые ниже, были на уровне выше списка

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю конечную цель, но вижу вновь ошибку с циклами, которую описал в других ваших вопросах, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136523/200899)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй сделать пустые места в svarka2

```
svarka2 = []
    for item in items:
        svarka2.append({
            "stranica": item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href'),
            "1": 1,
            "2": 2,
            })
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло