# Сохраняет последний элемент, вместо множества элементов

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Сделал парсер, чтобы выгружал текст с картинкой, сделал отдельный список для картинок, пытаюсь добавить в список для вывода, но сохраняет, не все элементы, а только последний. Пожалуйста подскажите, что делать?

Сам код:

```
import uuid
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'
HOST = 'upload/image/'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_Stranic(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    stranica_svarka=[]
    for item in items:
        stranica_svarka.append(
            item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href'),
            )
    return stranica_svarka

def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    image = []
    for item in items:
        image.append(
            item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src')
            )
    return  image

def get_html_vivod(stranic, img):
    for i in img:
        img_way = i.split('/')[-1]
    svarka = []
    for url in stranic:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        r = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('article', class_='b-product__wrapper')
        for item in items:
            svarka.append({
                "title": item.find('h1', class_='b-product__title').get_text(strip=True),
                "articul": item.find('div', class_='b-product__meta').get_text(strip=True).replace('Артикул: ',''),
                "price": item.find('span', class_='b-products__price').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', '').replace('р', '.00').replace('\xa0', ''),
                "text": item.find('div', class_='b-product-tab__main').get_text(strip=True),
                "image": HOST + img_way
                })
    return svarka

def save_file(svarka, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Артикул', 'Цена', 'Подробное описание', 'Картинка'])
        global item
        for item in svarka:
            writer.writerow((item.get("title"), item.get("articul"), item.get("price"), item.get("text"), item.get("image")))

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        stranic = get_Stranic(html.text)
        img = get_image(html.text)
        svarka = get_html_vivod(stranic, img)
        save_file(svarka, FILE)
        print(f' Получено {len(svarka)} сварочных аппаратов')
        os.startfile(FILE)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема как и в [другом вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132768/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) кроется в холостом цикле метода `get_html_vivod`

Цикл верно получает имена, но никуда их не сохраняет.

```
for i in img:
    img_way = i.split('/')[-1]
```

Вы можете использовать цикл с индексами

```
for index, value in enumerate('hello, world'):
    print(index, value)
```

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так

```
    for index, url in enumerate(stranic):
        ...
        for item in items:
            svarka.append({
                ...
                "image": HOST + img[index].split('/')[-1]
                })
```

Полный вариант

```
def get_html_vivod(stranic, img):
    svarka = []
    for index, url in enumerate(stranic):
        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).content
        items = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser').find_all('article', class_='b-product__wrapper')
        for item in items:
            svarka.append({
                "title": item.find('h1', class_='b-product__title').get_text(strip=True),
                "articul": item.find('div', class_='b-product__meta').get_text(strip=True).replace('Артикул: ',''),
                "price": item.find('span', class_='b-products__price').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', '').replace('р', '.00').replace('\xa0', ''),
                "text": item.find('div', class_='b-product-tab__main').get_text(strip=True),
                "image": HOST + img[index].split('/')[-1]
                })
    return svarka
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам, уже сижу несколько дней пытаюсь решить эту проблему